# WP8 upload file to skydrive in Background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, onedrive

I am developing `Windows Phone 8` app which collect the contact from **phone** and store it in `xml` file. I want to `upload` it to `skydrive` in `background`. I tried this

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = null;
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    fileStream = store.OpenFile("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var res = await client.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", "XMLFile1.xml", fileStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

This code works perfect. But when I press home key uploading gets stop. So **how can I upload file to skydrive in background even if user press `screen lock key` or `home key`**? And also want to know how **can I upload file to a particular folder in skydive?** Folders like Documents or Pictures.  How Can I use `client.BackgroundUploadAsync`? How can I pass `fileStream` object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using UploadAsync and it's cancelled when you leave your App. Because when you hit StartButton you are Navigating away from your App and as [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):
`When the user navigates forward, away from an app, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the app into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory.`
So your App gets Deactivation event and all threads and tasks are stopped. Everything should work all right if you stay in your App (as it's asynchronous).
**EDIT** - Downloading in background is possible by using [Background Transfers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
As you have spotted there is a method [BackgroundUploadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.backgrounduploadasync.aspx) and as it is said there:
`Begins uploading a file from Windows Phone isolated storage to Microsoft SkyDrive. The file upload should continue even if the app that starts the file upload quits or is suspended.`
It is allowed to download/upload files from/to directory shared/transfers/ (only this - so before you upload, your files must be copied there). The very simple code can look like this - start uploading async:

```
client.BackgroundTransferPreferences = BackgroundTransferPreferences.None; // check policies for this - with this you have to have your phone powered by external source and use WiFi
try
{
   client.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive", new Uri("shared/transfers/sample.txt", UriKind.Relative), OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
}
catch { }
```

But you must be aware that Background Transfers have its own [policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_BackgroundTransferPolicies) - you should really strong test your App before publishing.
Hope this helps.

Comment: But when I get back to app. My app get crashed. It give error `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SkyDrive_WP8_Upload_and_Download_Sample.UploadPage.<objContacts_SearchCompleted>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown`

Comment: It can be - as your transfer has been Stopped (cancelled) by OS (when you Navigate Away from App) and you didn't handeled Cancellation (you can provide your own TaskCancellationSource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#uploading_files), after return your App tries to perform next actions which probably will throw exception.

Comment: Can I resume it back after app is in active state?

Comment: Is there any option to upload it in background when user deactivate app. what is the use of `BackgroundUploadAsync`

Comment: I am trying to use `BackgroundUploadAsync` but how can I use `fileStream`?

Comment: @AjayPunekar Nah - sorry for mistake - it is possible - I was writing about UploadAsync - ouch, wait a while I'll try to correct my answer

Comment: Ok. I am confused where can I use fileStream. It is necessary to use to upload that file.

Comment: @AjayPunekar I've corrected my answer and also deleted those comments that weren't true. Once again sorry for confusion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46418/discussion-between-ajay-punekar-and-romasz)

Answer (score 1):

use this OneDriveChunkedUpload.cs to upload large files 
https://gist.github.com/ificator/3460d7b9d0bff74eb0ff

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Answer (score 0):

This PostCompleted event is use to upload your files in skydrive:

```
client.PostCompleted +=
                        new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(CreateMyFolder_Completed);
 void CreateMyFolder_Completed(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
               string folderID = (e.Result["id"]).ToString();
                foreach (string item in names)
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        string filename = item;
                        if (store.FileExists(filename))
                        {
                            IsolatedStorageFileStream storeStream = store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                            client.UploadAsync(folderID, filename, storeStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);

                        }                         
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: to upload into background use backgroundUploadAsynk method

Comment: I don't see any PostCompleted event. I only see PostAsync. How can I use backgroundUploadAsynk ?

Comment: private LiveConnectClient client;

Comment: use LiveConnectClient object to find this method

Comment: I used same in my project

Comment: i am using 5.3 version of skydrive sdk in that this method id present

Comment: I have two different solutions in one solution I can get PostCompleted and in one I can't. How this happen ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46408/discussion-between-ajay-punekar-and-pradeep-kesharwani)

Comment: use skydrive sdk in your main project and use from there